# Почему данные не добавляются в список?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase

При добавлении фотографии в firebase storage ссылка на эту фотографию должна добавляться в массив, для того, чтобы потом его добавить в firebase firestor, но у меня в итоге пустой список. Почему?
Код:

```
binding.ButtonIMG.setOnClickListener {

            //imageArray содержит массив из ссылок на фотографии
            val imageArray = imaganation.split(',').toMutableList()
            imageArray.removeAt(imageArray.size - 1)
            val imageRefArray = mutableListOf<String>()

            for (i in imageArray) {
                firestorage.getReference("images").child(System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
                    .putFile(i.toUri())
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        it.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                imageRefArray.add(it.toString())

                            }
                    }
            }

            val mapImgae = mapOf(
                "url" to imageRefArray //пустой список
            )
            firestore.collection("images").document("room1").set(mapImgae)


        }
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить `addOnFailureListener ` и посмотреть на логи

Comment: это тут не причём, когда я тост ставлю туда, то всё работает

Comment: ну как вариант у вас не дожидаясь запроса добавляет в словарь, попробуйте в слушателе success добавлять, а не за пределами